# Windows forms: Finding code that belongs to a button

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019

i have a very simple question but i just can't find the answer. I have an existing Windows forms project which shows me an interface with lots of different buttons when i run it in Visual Studio 2019.
Now i want to find a way to find the code belonging to a button. I already tried clicking the buttons, but nothing happens.

So my question is: How can i automatically jump to the code that is related to one of the buttons?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If double clicking doesn't work and in the properties window the event is not wired then just search for the name of your button in the code. You should see something like "MyButton.Click += <eventhandlername>;" <eventhandlername> is the name of the event handler code you want. Highlight it and press F12.

Comment: Code doesn't *belong* to Controls :) If you man the Event Handlers attached to Events of specific Controls, select a Control, go to the Properties Panel (`F4`), click the lightning bolt icon: it will show you all the Events of that object that have handlers attached.

Comment: My task is to comment the code and find out which part of the code defines which button. If i run the project and then click on one of the buttons there is nothing shown in the properties panel.

Comment: The Properties Panel is used at design-time. You need to specify what is *which part of the code defines which button* means. Controls are *defined* (constructed) in the Form's Designer file.

Comment: Ahh, so how do i get to the design mode? Sorry this is my first day of using Visual Studio

Comment: When you first open a Windows Forms Project, you are in design-mode. You should probably find a tutorial about this.

Comment: @Sophie_R, I have two questions about your question. First, you can choose the button in the designer, then please press 'F7' to find the related code. Second, you can search the button name like 'button1' by using 'CTRL+F'.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that when you say "the code belonging to a button", you are referring to the code that runs when the button is clicked. In this case there are several ways of getting to this code.

In Winforms (not sure about anything else) you should be able to double click on the button and visual studio should navigate automatically to the code in the Button.Click event. If there is no Button.Click event handler for the button, it will create one.

Another way to get there is to select the button in the designer and go to the properties window(press F4). In the properties window go to the events list(see images), then double click on the "Click" event in this list and you should be directed to the code in the Button.Click event handler. If there is none, it will create one.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I hope this helps. If not, provide more details about your issue.